# Excel 365 - want FILTER function to output results as if I was using the built in table filters

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data set for grant programs that I want to filter using checkboxes for 6 categories. The headers are "group" "individual" "for profit" "non profit" "operational funding" & "project funding".

When I've tried using the filter function it is only displaying results that match the categories exactly and I'd like it to filter as if I was using the built in drop down table filters.

This is my formula:

```
=FILTER(Grants,(Grants[Group]=B2)*(Grants[Individual]=B3)*(Grants[Operational Funding]=B4)*(Grants[Organizational Funding]=B5)*(Grants[For Profit]=B6)*(Grants[Non Profit]=B7),"no matches")
```

For example:

If I check the box for "group", I'd like it to display grants that groups can apply for. But using this formula, it only returns values that are TRUE for "group" but false for everything else. So I'm missing results that are TRUE for "group" and may be true for any of the other categories.

Sample table below:

| Grant | Group | Individual | Op Funding | Org Funding | Profit | Non Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grant #1 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Grant #2 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Grant #3 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Grant #4 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Grant #5 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help), then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777225/edit) your question to provide more details such as your Excel version. Please provide an example file, the function/formula you currently use, example of the desired result and example of the actual result. To keep your question up to date and everything relevant available please don't add new info in comments but by editing your question.

Comment: The Microsoft FILTER page has examples on how to use two columns in your criteria: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: Give us sample formulas you tried that do not work (or do)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
=FILTER(Grants,IF(B2=FALSE,1,(Grants[Group]=B2))*IF(B3=FALSE,1,(Grants[Individual]=B3))*IF(B4=FALSE,1,(Grants[Operational Funding]=B4))*IF(B5=FALSE,1,(Grants[Organizational Funding]=B5))*IF(B6=FALSE,1,(Grants[For Profit]=B6))*IF(B7=FALSE,1,(Grants[Non Profit]=B7)),"no match")
```